# Change background color of child div on hover of parent div?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the background color of child div on hover of the parent div. Currently, I am able to change the color but only on hover on child div. However, I want to change the color on hover of parent div as well.

```
<div class="content">
<div class="logo">Button</div> 
</div>

<style>
.content {
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
width:300px; height:250px;
background-color:blue;
overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
margin:50px auto;
background:yellow;
text-align:center;
}

.logo:hover {
background: red;
}
</style>
```

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/bCkpb/10/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CSS you can do this:

```
.parent:hover .child, .parent.hover .child { background: green; }
```

Here is the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/bCkpb/17/

Comment: Your code looks odd. Shouldn't it be .content:hover, content:hover .logo {background: green; }

Comment: It looks odd (especially the .parent.hover part) but it is working as expected.