# CSS Image not scaling on hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover, overlay

I've made a responsive image grid and am trying to add a hover effect to it so that the image gets a dark overlay and some text fades in on it. However, I've been having a tough time implementing it.

Here's my HTML structure.

```html
<div class="tile">
        <img src="some_image" class="animate">
        <div class="overlay">
        <p>Mahatma Gandhi</p>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS

```css
.gallery .row .tile:hover ~ .tile img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

However upon hovering over the image, it does not have the expected behaviour.

What's wrong?

**EDIT**
I got the hover effect to work and I can now fade in text.

Here's my code for that:

```html
<div class="tile">
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d6/Tagore_Gandhi.jpg/220px-Tagore_Gandhi.jpg" class="animate">
                        <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="text">Mahatma Gandhi</div>
                            </div>
                      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tile {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.tile:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This seems to work but I think it doesnt have a certain "feel" to it. So I need to add a scale effect to the image. How can I do that

Comment: yeah, it kinda worked but the whole image scaled up, I want the image to be contained inside some kind of container div and i can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a jsFiddle that i think will help you to resolve your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/mcs3yn1x/

**HTML**

```
<div class="tile">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="animate">
 <div class="overlay">
 <p>Mahatma Gandhi</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tile {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.tile:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

**Edit**

After hearing alittle more about your issue I have created the following jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f1gzonjr/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="tile">
  <div class="container">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="animate">
   <div class="overlay">
    <p>Mahatma Gandhi</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tile {
  position: relative;

  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;

  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;

  overflow: hidden;

  border: 2px solid black;
} 

.container:hover img{
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.overlay{
 position: absolute;
 display: none;

 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;

 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;

 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.overlay p {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;

 color: #fff;
}

.tile:hover .overlay{
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: yeah, it kinda worked but the whole image scaled up, I want the image to be contained inside some kind of container div and i can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: This answer's perfect, but u see i changed my code a bit (i'll update it rn) and i can't use your code in my current solution. Sorry I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution. Not sure if its what you wanted.

```
.tile:hover img, .tile.hover img {transform: scale(1.2);}
```

Here is the original answer that I adapted: [Change background color of child div on hover of parent div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086312/change-background-color-of-child-div-on-hover-of-parent-div)

-----EDIT-----

To stop it scaling and breaking responsiveness you will need to add a container around the image and then set overflow to none.

HTML:

```
<div class="tile">
    <div class="img-container"><img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/16C0E/production/_109089139_928b0174-4b3f-48ff-8366-d118afa1ed56.jpg" class="animate"></div>
    <div class="overlay">
    <p>Mahatma Gandhi</p>
```

CSS:

```
.img-container{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tile:hover img, .tile.hover img {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

See the codepen below for an example
https://codepen.io/jamesCyrius/pen/pooqwwv

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code

```css
.zoom {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom"></div>
```